# Fancybox: make group of photos with the each() of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

In the standart case we can create a photo gallery (group of photos) by doing the next:

```
$( '.fancybox' ).fancybox();
```

In HTML we must to set the attribute **rel** of the tag 'a' to the same value:

```
<a rel="group" title="" href="/profile/photos/files/74.jpeg" class="fancybox no-tooltip" id="photo-link-74"><img class="image-curving" style="display: block;" alt="" src="/profile/photos/files/74_thumb.jpeg"></a>
<a rel="group" title="" href="/profile/photos/files/74.jpeg" class="fancybox no-tooltip" id="photo-link-74"><img class="image-curving" style="display: block;" alt="" src="/profile/photos/files/74_thumb.jpeg"></a>
```

What about the situation when we want to use each() of jQuery?

```
        $(".fancybox").each(    
            function()
            {
                var parentId = $( this ).parent().parent().attr( 'id' );
                var id = parentId.substring( parentId.indexOf( '-' ) + 1, parentId.length );

                $( this ).fancybox(
                    {
                        minWidth: 600,
                        afterShow: function() { afterShow( id ); },
                        title: "<img href='/pics/indikator.gif'>",
                        helpers: 
                        {
                            title: 
                            {
                                type : 'inside'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
```

In the last case the photos will not be grouped. How can I handle the function `each()` and make all photos grouped for which the rel attribute is the same?

Comment: Why are you even using `each`? Simply iterate over all your elements, give them a `rel` attribute to group them, then invoke the fancybox *once*.

Comment: @Asad I would like to use closure variables **parentId** and **id**. I do not realize if it is possible with your approach. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @Asad Thank you for the idea to iterate.

Comment: what does `afterShow: function() { afterShow( id ); }` do? ... what is the idea behind using `each()`? I think is redundant.

Comment: @JFK The problem is that **id** is not an index but a value from an array which we have to retrieve from an attribute of a parent node.

Comment: Then you don't need `each()`, just get the parent's `id` on the fly within a regular fancybox custom script, using a fancybox callback like `afterShow: function(){$(this.element).parent().parent().attr('id');}` ... notice I used `$(this.element)` because that is the way to refer to `$(this)` inside fancybox callbacks

Comment: @JFK Thank you. It's correct. Publish your answer please, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `each()`, just get the parent's `id` on the fly within a regular fancybox custom script, using a fancybox callback like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   afterShow: function(){
       var parentId = $(this.element).parent().parent().attr('id');
       // do something with that variable
   }
});
```

... **notice** I used `$(this.element)` because that is the way to refer to `$(this)` inside fancybox callbacks. Also you could declare all your variables at the top of your scripts to make them accessible anytime.

Answer (score 1):

The next is not universal, but works when we have one gallery on the page:

```
        var ids = [];
        var index = 0;

        $( '.fancybox' ).each(
            function()
            {
                var parentId = $( this ).parent().parent().attr( 'id' );
                var id = parentId.substring( parentId.indexOf( '-' ) + 1, parentId.length );
                ids[ index ] = id;
                index++;
            }
        );

        $( ".fancybox" ).fancybox(
            {
                minWidth: 600,
                afterShow: function() { afterShow( ids[ $.fancybox.current.index ] ); },
                title: "<img href='/pics/indikator.gif'>",
                helpers: 
                {
                    title: 
                    {
                        type : 'inside'
                    }
                }
            }               
        );
```

Thanks to Asad who gave me the idea to iterate.

If someone has more clear decision (without external variables, but using closure variables only) please publish it here.